# Odds of finding a suitable day

Tags: probability

Let's say we have a group of $15$ people (though we can perhaps generalize this for $n$ people), all of whom have 2 days (or $k$ days, if you want) off per week. We can assume the days you have off are random every week.

What are the odds that you find a day where all 15 people have a day off? This question is based on a real life situation I'm facing.

Is it simply $(2/7)^{15}$?

Comment: Idea: fix a day of the week. Think about the probability of a single person having a day off on the same day you fixed. Them extend it to 2 people having a day off on the same day.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite.

$(2/7)^{15}$ is the probability a given day is in everybody's choices, if each individual's $2$ choices are uniformly distributed across the $7$ days and are independent of all the others' choices. That is a strong assumption and in my view is improbable.

The probability of any of the $7$ days facing that position is almost $7$ times that and can be calculated exactly using inclusion-exclusion.